# Making a new column based on a derived column sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a single table called TOY_DETAILS within are ID,Date,Toy_obje,currency(can be USD, GBP or EUR) and budget.

Now I want to make a sql query that will return everything along with

1. A computed column that will have the budget in terms of dollars(so conversion rate is like 1 pound = 1.5 dollars and 1 euro = 1.2)
2. Another computed column that will have the total budget in dollars.

What I've tried.

```
SELECT ID, Date,Toy_object, currency, budget, 
CASE currency
WHEN 'GBP' THEN budget*1.5
WHEN 'EUR' THEN budget*1.2
ELSE budget
END AS USD_Value
(SELECT SUM(USD_Value) FROM PROJECT_DETAILS) AS Total_Budget
FROM PROJECT_DETAILS
```

My problem is 2). Where I want a Total_Budget to be the SUM of the column USD_Value, however I can't type 'SUM(USD_Value)' cause that 'column doesn't exist' ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: But what do you want to group by?

Comment: Hi, no grouping is really required. But I got an answer below, thanks for having a look at my question though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeat the `CASE` expression inside the `SUM`:

```
SELECT ID, Date,Toy_object, currency, budget, 
       CASE currency 
          WHEN 'GBP' THEN budget*1.67 
          WHEN 'EUR' THEN budget*1.3 
       ELSE budget END AS USD_Value,
       SUM(CASE currency 
              WHEN 'GBP' THEN budget*1.67 
              WHEN 'EUR' THEN budget*1.3 
              ELSE budget 
            END) OVER() AS Total_Budget 
FROM PROJECT_DETAILS
```

Comment: Thanks very much Giorgos, I was thinking something similar but I thought I would end up in some recursive pool definitely due to my lack sql knowledge! I will accept this answer as the right answer, thanks again.

Comment: @TooManyProblems Have a look at the edit I made: you can use the window version of `SUM`. There is no need for a sub-query.

Comment: Interesting, Is the 'OVER' is allowing you to place aggregated data along side the retrieved data?